# How to get a random number in specific range using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way to run in my Node script command that gets a random number from 0.01 to 10.85 for example. The number must look like 0.01 and not like 0.000000001.

How can I do this?

My current command:

```
var randomTicket = helper.getRandomInt(0, 10.85);
```

That command for some reason it returns only the number 0

Are there any other alternative ways?

Answer (score 0):

Math.random would do the trick. It returns a value between [0,1) (1 is exclusive). Then you scale the range by the difference between max and min and add min as offset.

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

But because you get a float value, you can not clip the decimal after the second position. You can format it to a string. I'm not sure but this should work.

```
var number = getRandomArbitrary(0.01, 10.85);
var numString = number.toFixed(2);
```

## EDIT

If you only generate integers then multiply min and max by 100.0 and divide the result by 100.0.

```
var number = getRandomArbitrary(1.0, 1085.0);
var numString = (number / 100.0).toFixed(2);
```

or

```
var number = getRandomInt(1, 1085);
var numString = (number / 100.0).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Any way i can do it based on getRandomInt?

Comment: I know that getRandomInt is for integer but there is something similar like that? to get insted of 0-1-2-3-4-5 to get 0.01 0.02 ... 10.00 10.08 etc...

Comment: Sorry, I don't now the helper object/module. But I will change my answer to the case where you only generate integers.